# Get all subarrays from an array using a single loop

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, arrays

I was wondering if there is an algorithm / pattern where someone could get/parse all subarrays of a given  array
using for example a simple loop.

For example: for the array  `myArray{0,1,2,3}`    I need

```
myArray(0,0)myArray(0,1),myArray(0,2),myArray(0,3)
myArray(1,1)myArray(1,2),myArray(1,3)
myArray(2,2)myArray(2,3),
myArray(3,3)
```

**I do not want** to use something like

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < myArray.length; j++)
    {

    }
}
```

since I want my algorithm to be faster.

Comment: Language tag would be helpful.Not an alternative approach, but I think `j = 1` might need to be `j = i + 1`.

Comment: Consider the size of your algorithm's output. It is quadratic in the size of the input.

Comment: @ehudt well, `n**2 / 2`. Still, a nested loop is probably the best way to accomplish this. It could be done in a single loop but it wouldn't be any faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int myArray[] = {0,1,2,3};
    int myArrayLength = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray);
    int i, j;
    for(j=i=0;i<myArrayLength;++i){
        printf("(%d,%d)", myArray[j], myArray[i]);
        if(i == myArrayLength -1){
            i = j++;//++j - 1;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you give an example this is printing sub array like: (0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)
(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)
(2,2)(2,3)
(3,3)
 but some pairs like:(1,1),(2,2),(3,3) are not the part of array because there are no two two's, three's and once's.

Comment: @singh.indolia see OP's example. `(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)` are included.

Comment: in your example these are included but in array there are not two 3 ,2 and 1.

Comment: @singh.indolia _I need

myArray(0,0)myArray(0,1),myArray(0,2),myArray(0,3)
myArray(1,1)myArray(1,2),myArray(1,3)
myArray(2,2)myArray(2,3),
myArray(3,3)_

Comment: @singh.indolia Why do you decide the OP's request? At least my answer is that.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to modify the initialization of `j` from `j = 0` to `j = i` and iterate over all the possible pairs. Example of implementation (Java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
    List<Integer[]> res = allPairs(arr);
    for(Integer[] tmp : res) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
    }
}

private static List<Integer[]> allPairs(int [] myArray) {
    List<Integer[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            Integer[] tmp = new Integer[2];
            tmp[0] = myArray[i];
            tmp[1] = myArray[j];
            res.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 4]
```

Comment: If the downvoters would only care to comment, maybe this answer could be improved...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find all sub arrays of an array so first of all you should understand that sub arrays of an array should be continuous but in case of string there is not necessary of continuous for example: if we have an array like:[1,2,3], in this case there are sub arrays like: (1),(2),(3),(1,2),(2,3),(1,2,3).
Program to generate sub arrays of an array :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Prints all subarrays in arr[0..n-1]
void subArray(int arr[], int n)
{

    for (int i=0; i <n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j<n; j++)
        {
            for (int k=i; k<=j; k++)
                cout << arr[k] << " ";

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << "All Non-empty Subarrays\n";
    subArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question said 1 loop not 3 nested loops, yours is having the time complexity of `O(n^3)`